# pip looking in wrong folder

Tags: python, pip

My issue requires some backstory.

I was having some troubles with pip, so I reinstalled Python.  After the reinstall pip began to work, but Pycharm, my IDE, could no longer find Python.  When I reinstalled Python it created a new folder for itself (Python310), but Pycharm kept looking in the old folder (Python39).  I couldn't figure out how to get Pycharm to look in the new folder.  Even deleting and reinstalling it did nothing.

So, I renamed Python310 to Python39 and changed the PATH.  Now Pycharm can find Python.  But pip has developed a new and exciting error.  When I try to use it I get the following message:

`Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install numpy': The system cannot find the file specified.`

If I read this correctly pip is still trying to look in Python310.  Would you please tell me what I need to do to get pip to looking in the right place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, to start. You don't fix this by renaming the folder where the interpreter resides. Even if that worked, it's not a fix. The name will say one thing, but it's actual version, compatible libraries, and anything else tied to the version number would be incorrect.

If you take a close look at the error message from pip, it tells us what's wrong.

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"  "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\pip.exe" install numpy': The system cannot find the file specified.

You renamed the directory, so your IDE can find it, but pip and everything else using the Python interpreter is still configured to look in the Python39 directory to find it.

The problem you are having is that your IDE, PyCharm, needs to be configured for your project. You have to tell it where the Python interpreter is. The simple solution, you can rename your your Python folder back to it's original state, and add it to your project.

1. Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the project Settings/Preferences and go to Project  | Python Interpreter. Click the Add Interpreter link next to the list of the available interpreters.
2. Expand the list of the available interpreters and click the Show All link.
3. Select the target interpreter.
   In your case, look for the one with this file path: "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe"

I would recommend going one step futher and create an interpreter in a virtual environment. Especially if you are interested in Python beyond a very casual hobby. They are unavoidable.

This link is a good source and can help you with this:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html#interpreter

There, you will find screenshots that follow the steps I listed above. There are also detailed instructions on how to create and add a new interpreter in a virtual environment. The relevant headings are as follows:

- Configure a Python interpreter
- Python interpreters in PyCharm
- Setting an existing Python interpreter
- Creating a new Python interpreter

The rest of the content is great as well, and may help answer questions you didn't know you had.

Comment: This is good advice but unfortunately it doesn't really answer the question, since the actual answer is only in the linked page. Please include the essential parts of your linked page here so your answer remains useful even if the links breaks. Please take the tour and see [Answer] and [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/174780). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you, @PranavHosangadi. I think my answer now has the required information in itself, with a little extra advice. I will review those links after I settle in at work!

Comment: Could maybe highlight in the first part that OPs error clearly shows that it does not work.

Comment: Good suggestion. I think I was able to fit that in there neatly without being too verbose or confusing. Thanks, @FlyingTeller

Answer (score -1):

try to uninstall all of the existing python versions. and install it again. using any of application allow you to delete most of files, so to prevent error when re-install .

Answer (score -1):

Option 1:

delete and reinstall again. and then when creating a project it should prompt you to pick a basic interpreter, choose python310 or whatever version you're using.

Option 2:

use a different IDE.